# For loops to Idiomatic Python

Tags: python

**OBJECTIVE**

This program has a few arithmetic calculations inside one for loop. I was looking for a better idiomatic solution to this. e.g. if I can do it with a compact list comprehension or something better than a list comprehension?

```
import random

def diff_avg(first, second):
    s = set()
    len1 = len(first)
    len2 = len(second)
    if len1 == len2:
        for i in range(len1-1):
            n = first[i+1] - first[i]
            p = second[i+1] - second[i]
            k = p//n
            v = p%n
            s.add(k + v)
    
    len3 = len(s)
    if(len3 < len1):
        return F"Non-Unique value(s) = {len1 - len3}"
    else:
        return F"Celebrate: https://youtu.be/2uMNtOQOaLU"

print("\n------------------------------------------------------------------\n")

first2= random.sample(range(10), k=6)
second2 =  [x*random.randrange(7) for x in first2]
print(F"List-1: {first2}")
print(F"List-2: {second2}")
print(F"{diff_avg(first2, second2)}")
```

Comment: Code review requests tend to get downvoted as off-topic and/or too broad; perhaps explore whether this would be suitable for our sibling site [codereview.se]

Comment: **For-loops are idiomatic**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use a list comprehension:

```py
return [(price[i + 1] - price[i]) / (sqft[i + 1] - sqft[i]) for i in range(l1 - 1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

A handy way to perform operations on associated lists is the `zip` function.  This also works for operations on a list and a smaller slice of that list, similar to the operation you're doing by iterating over pairs of indices:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> [(x, y) for x, y in zip(a, a[1:])]
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

In general it's considered more idiomatic to use `for` loops to iterate over elements of a collection directly than to iterate over the `range` of its `len` and then use the indices to get back to the elements -- so the "idiomatic" way to perform this operation IMO would be to use `zip` to define generators for `n` and `d`, and then in turn zip THOSE together to produce your result:

```
def stats100(sqft, price):
    if len(sqft) != len(price):
        raise ValueError("Both arguments should be lists of exact same size")
    return [
        n / d for n, d in zip(
            (p1 - p0 for p0, p1 in zip(price, price[1:])),
            (a1 - a0 for a0, a1 in zip(sqft, sqft[1:]))
        )
    ]
```

As another commenter pointed out, printing an error and returning `None` is definitely not idiomatic; instead you should `raise` an exception when your function can't return the value that it's supposed to return.  That way the calling code has the option of catching it with an `except` and doing something other than simply printing the message.

Answer (score 0):

Going through elements rather than indexes is the more "Pythonic" way.  In this case you want to manipulate two consecutive elements which is generally done using zip() to combine the list with an offset on itself:

```
s = [1700, 2100, 1900, 1300, 1600, 2200]
p = [53000, 65000, 59000, 41000, 50000, 68000]

r = [ (p1-p0)/(s1-s0) for s0,s1,p0,p1 in zip(s,s[1:],p,p[1:]) ]

print(r) # [30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0]
```